# jQuery .hover plugin wordpress

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm a new using jQuery, I need to modify a plugin for wordpress that is used to scroll to top when you visit bottom part.

Normally scroll top icon has a grey color, and I want that on hover there is other color on it. Below js code for it without hover function:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

below function that active color blue on hover that works

```
 $('.scrollup').hover(function () {
           $(this).css({"background-color":"blue"});
});
```

..Now what I should add to remove hover when element hasn't focus?
Thank you so much.

Comment: hi,

i think to solve adding a function in this way:

     $('.scrollup').hover(function () {
               $(this).css({"background-color":"green"});
    }, function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"grey"});
    });

is there other better solution?

thank you